# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 on a Blazor app published in Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, blazor

Basically what is happening is that I have published an app made in Blazor into AWS Beanstalk, creating a new Environment and everything from Visual Studio 19.

I already done this in azure, and is working. But I wanted to test it in AWS, but I get that error.

The Logs in the Environment are empty. I don't know where to check the error, or whatever is happening.

[Error from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGgup.png)
Framework: .NET 5

[Beanstalk Configuration overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qdzZ.png)

Comment: Are you using Blazor WebAssembly or Blazor Server? Also I would suggest to open your "Browser Dev Tools" and check the `Console`, what is written there

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured out how to fix it!!

What I did in Elastic Beanstalk:

1. Into the Configuration of the Environment.
2. Clic on Edit for Software Option.
3. On Environment Properties I added a new one:

NAME:  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

VALUE: Development

4. Then the app is gonna start working!! :D

Comment: I have similar config with same issue. Adding this to the sofware configuration did not solve the problem.  just error : The connection has timed out. console is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to the answer by @cramtek;

***Never*** use development environment while exposing the application to the outside network. It's a serious security flaw, always make sure it is set to ***Production***

Comment: this should be posted as a comment NOT as an answer

Comment: Couldn't comment to his answer because of my reputation level or smth. I am aware that this isn't an answer to the question itself. That's why I wrote "Replying to the answer by..". No need to be sensitive about it.